# Error creating a multi-step form using Django session

Tags: django, django-forms, django-formwizard

I'm currently working on building a multi-step registration form in Django. I followed the official documentation which can be seen [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/sessions/#setting-test-cookies). Although the forms do not show any error, the user does not get created. Is there a problem I might be overlooking?

```
def signup_step_one(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('accounts:personal-signup'))
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                # collect form data in step 1
                email = form.cleaned_data['email']
                password = form.cleaned_data['password1']

                # create a session and assign form data variables
                request.session['email'] = email
                request.session['password'] = password
                
                return render(request, 'personal-signup-step-2.html', context={
                    'form': form,
                    "title": _('Create your personal account | Step 1 of 2'),
                })
        else:
            form = CustomUserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'personal-signup-step-1.html', {
        "title": _('Create your personal account | Step 1 of 2'),
        'form': form,
    })


def signup_step_two(request):
    # create variables to hold session keys
    email = request.session['email']
    password = request.session['password']

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.email = email
            user.set_password(password)
            user.first_name(form.cleaned_data['first_name'])
            user.last_name(form.cleaned_data['last_name'])
            user.save()
            print('user created')
        return HttpResponse('New user created')
    else:
        form = CustomUserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'personal-signup-step-2.html', {
        "title": _('Create your account | Step 2 of 2'),
        'form': form,
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the following line in signup_step_two function will always return the message "New user created" even if form is not valid:

```
  return HttpResponse('New user created')
```

Put the above line inside the if statement. Also print form.errors in else statement or inside the template to check the problem.
Ex:

```
    if form.is_valid():
        # create the user
        return HttpResponse('New user created')
    else:
        print(form.errors)
```

Comment: `<ul class="errorlist"><li>email<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>password1<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></u
l></li><li>password2<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>`

@Ajeet I noticed the above error. This means the form is not using the data in the user session. I wonder what could be the cause.

Comment: You are using the same form CustomUserCreationForm in both views. These 3 fields are required. So, you need to submit email, password1 and password2 in the form inside personal-signup-step-2.html as well. If you don't want to show these to user again, you can send them as hidden input type.

Comment: Another option is to use different form for signup_step_two view. Form will have fields first_name, last_name only and you can set other things like email and password from session in same way as you are doing now.

Comment: I tried both suggestions, none worked. To be sure the information I collected is done correctly, I printed the email and password from the `request.session['email']` and `request.session['password']` in the template.